# Slide Out on Hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate, toggle

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#slide").delay(5000).animate({right: 0}, 500);
});
```

```css
#slide {
  position: absolute;
  right: -155px; overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slide"><img src="pic.jpg"></div>
```

Right now my code is working with a delay of 5 seconds then the photo slides out from the right side. I need to change this so it stays in the "right:-155" position until you hover over the image. Once you hover it should slide out to "0" and hold it there for about 6 seconds. If the user moves the mouse off it should just go back to the original position.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#slide").hover(function (e) {
        $(this).stop().delay(5000).animate({
            right: e.type === "mouseenter" ? 0 : "-155px"
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Or better toggle some class.

Comment: that will work... i just took the delay 5000 off though, on the rollover it does not stay open for 5 secs

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle, i skipped some part of your question, my bad

Comment: is there anyway to get rid of the scroll bars since its moving on and off screen?

Comment: But if you cannot scroll to element, how could you put cursor over this element?

Comment: half of the image is sticking out, and then the rest of it shows when you scroll over

Comment: @user3357774 of course seems logic after all ;) You should set overflow hidden on #slide parent which i don't know what is it

Comment: thats the problem there isnt a parent div

Comment: @user3357774 you could animate the width instead see: http://jsfiddle.net/w7ybb/1/   ( thx `@AlexThomas` for funny picture ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the game, and I see you already have a "working" answer, however, think this works slightly better:

```
$('#slide').hover(function () {
    $(this).stop( true, true ).animate({right: 0}, 500);
    timeout = window.setTimeout(function(){
        $('#slide').trigger('mouseleave');        
    }, 5000);
},function(){
    window.clearTimeout(timeout);
    $(this).animate({right: -500}, 500);  
});
```

Here it is in action - http://jsfiddle.net/w7ybb/